# Opinion on data storage

Tags: java, tomcat, data-structures, storage

I have an upcoming project where the core of it will be storing a mapping between two integers. ( 1234 in column A maps to 4567 in column B). There are roughly 1000 mappings.  A lookup on the mappings will be done every time a user hits a certain url on the site.

It seems like inserting it into our relational database is overkill.  The overhead of selecting it out on every hit seems high.  On the other hand, storing it an XML file and loading that flat file from disk every time theres a hit, also seems less than optimal.

So my question is this: what is the ideal data structure and method to persist this mapping?

The system architecture is tomcat + apache + mysql. The code will be running in tomcat.

EDIT:
Mappings are static, I won't need to change them. Seems like the XML file in a hashmap is the way to go.

Comment: I've never used your system architecture, but if I'd try to do the same thing in .NET, I'd probably have an XML file that was loaded on startup of the application and kept in-memory (perhaps in a hash table). This approach, of course, assumes that the mappings will not change between requests, but if they do using a relational database is not overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a properties file or an XML file, load it into memory (as a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`) on startup and then just serve from the hashmap.

If you need to *change* the mapping at execution time, you could either write it back immediately or potentially just write changes incrementally (and update the in-memory map), with a process to unify the original file and the changes on startup. This doesn't work terribly well if you need to scale to multiple servers, of course - at that point you need to work out what sort of consistency you need etc. A database is *probably* the simplest way of proceeding, but it depends on the actual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I agree a relational database seems a bit of overkill. You may want to look at a NoSQL database. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is my personal favourite, but there are plenty out there. Do a search on `NoSQL databases`.

A NoSQL database will allow you to store this mapping as a simple document, with extremely faster searching and updating of the data. Obviously it's another technology in your stack though, so that's something for you to consider.

Comment: Employing NoSQL for it is even more of an overkill. :-)

Comment: I don't think you can comment on whether it's overkill based on the information provided. If you're going to be searching on integers, updating them in parallel, adding and deleting new mappings then it may well not be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an in-memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). The memory footprint will likely be larger than with in-memory hashmap and file, but on the upside you can use SQL for querying and updating and don't need to worry about concurrent access.